# Homework: Testing square with all equal rows

Tags: c++

So for my current homework assignment, I have to determine whether the sum of all the rows in a square are equal, if they are all equal then the square is 'Awesome' otherwise 'Not Awesome'. In this program the first input is the number of squares you want to solve and then for each square you enter how many rows it will have, followed by a series of integers to represent each number in the 'square'. Below is my tried and tested code, for me, I cant seem to come up with a test case that breaks it, yet when I upload it for grading, the grading bot fails it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

At first I thought it was an overflow issue, so I changed the sum and temp variables to long long but it had no effect.

input examples:

3

4

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

3

1 2 3

2 3 1

3 2 7

5

1 2 3 4 5

1 1 1 1 11

2 2 2 2 7

3 3 3 3 3

4 4 4 4 -1

output would be:

Awesome

Not Awesome

Awesome

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numTests, numRows, i, col, row, firstRun;
    long long sum, prevSum, temp;

    cin >> numTests;
    for (i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        firstRun = 1;
        cin >> numRows;
        for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (col = 0; col < numRows; col++)
            {
                cin >> temp;
                sum += temp;
            }
            if (!firstRun && prevSum != sum)
                break;
            firstRun = 0;
            prevSum = sum;
        }
        if (row != numRows)
            cout << "Not ";
        cout << "Awesome" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: any input exemple ?

Comment: Your question says that the output should be "awesome" or "not awesome", while your code writes "Awesome" or "Not Awesome". Could it be an upper-/lower-case issue?

Comment: Its not a upper/lower case issue, the online tester doesnt care about case. I updated my question to include an input example

Comment: What about a number of rows that overflows an `int`? is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are breaking the loop when you get the answer . But input may not finish .

```
1
4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 1
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Here , your loop will break after inputting second row . Thus the subsequent numbers are treating wrongly and causing WA . Consider the case

```
2
3
1 2 3 
1 2 1
3 2 1
3
3 1 1
1 1 3
1 3 1
```

Your program will print

```
Not Awesome
Not Awesome
```